# API Controller Routing in .NET 6 Doesn't Work Any More

Tags: asp.net-web-api-routing, .net-6.0

I'm trying to create a standard WebAPI project in .NET 6. I notice that the standard ApiController route doesn't have the leading api route that I like to have. When I add it, the controller breaks. It doesn't give me a 404 (not found), it just gives me that index page that says that I have to enable javascript. I'm really at a loss at what I have to do to make my app work where I can put `api` at the start of my routes:
`[Route("api/[controller]")]`

I've tried adding it to the default controller route map in different combinations. I've tried adding the `UseEndpoints` method in the Program class. I'm just not sure what to differently in 6.

For those who want to "see my code", I'm just using the standard WebAPI project w/ React (NO Redux!).

Comment: I have been looking at this and it does seem to be caused by this having a SPA client app involved. I can get this to work w/ other Web API projects that aren't serving up and Angular or React frontend.

Comment: I have decided to go with creating our front ends in separate ReactJS projects created with react and not as a SPA in the Web API project. I liked how a single project could handle the front end and back end w/o CORs, but CORs isn't that difficult and while I have two projects now, they are both much lighter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the new setupProxy.js file [image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiEcb.png) inside the ClientApp folder, you need to configure the backend routes in the proxy config, I had a similar issue with the ASP.NET Core 6.0 with Angular project template, you can find more information here [link 1](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/27887)  [link 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/636698/how-to-connect-a-framwork-with-net-6.html)

Comment: Thank you; that appears to be it. I found that I had to be very careful about matching letter-case not only between the controller cs file and the setupProxy.js files, but when calling the endpoint from an HTTP client (or just Postman). I realize the HTTP routes are mostly case-sensitive, but I haven't known .NET (Core) to be so picky about it. I'm just happy that my old code can move up to .NET6 and won't be stuck on 5 when 8 or higher is coming out!

Comment: I might add that my plan B was to just go with Azure Static WebApps for my front end. With the kind of enterprise applications that I write, it's convenient to have the SPA and API in the same for development/deployment reasons, but maybe it's time to make the .NET projects strictly WebAPI which is what at least one of the links that you furnished implied. (I admit that I haven't had time to read them thoroughly)